# Menu item shows up when Tab is changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem, fragment-tab-host

I'm using fragments and I have a menu item in one of my fragments. The fragment that  uses the menu item is called when an item in the List View is clicked. When the fragment with the menu item is called, and then I change the tab, the menu item is still there. I want the menu item to only show in the one fragment only.

Here is the code for Tab 1

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setHasOptionsMenu(false);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Tab 2");

        initView();
}

private void initView() {
        ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_text)).setText("Tab 2");
        Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        replaceFragment();
                }
        });
}

private void replaceFragment() {
        ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(new Tab2AddOnFragment(), true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

}

and Here is the code for Tab 3 which has the List View

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Ang na  Ang na", "Sulakihin", "Somaskidot", "Moko Moko"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getActivity().setTitle("Tab 3");
}




@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch(position){
    case 0:
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        replaceFragment();  
        transaction.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
        break;
    default:
    }

}

private void replaceFragment() {
     ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(new FragmentInListView(), true);
}
```

}

and here is the code for the fragment with the menu item

```
public class FragmentInListView extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Fragment Called in Tab 3(List View)");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment,
            container, false);
        TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
        tv.setText("Fragment in List View"); 
        return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.travel_tips_expanded, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

}

and here is the code for the menu of the fragment with a menu item

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="favorite"/>
```

Here is an image of the Fragment called when an item in the List View is clicked. And it contains the menu item.

http://s904.photobucket.com/user/fookywooky/media/tab4_zps30944a6e.png.html

And here is an image of the Fragment called when "Tab 2" is selected. As you can see, the menu item is still there but i don't want it to be there. Also, this is the case even if you click Tab 1 and Tab 3. The menu item is still there.

http://s904.photobucket.com/user/fookywooky/media/tab5_zps285c8314.png.html

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accurately determine when to show the `Fragment` menu, your `Activity` needs some indication as to which `Fragment` is visible and current. You can accomplish this with the `setMenuVisibility()` and `setUserVisibleHint()` methods. In your `OnTabChanged()` callback, set the menu visibility and user visible hint to false in the previously selected `Fragment` and true in the currently selected `Fragment`.